# Wordpress thumbnail images in Google Bucket

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Recently started using Google Cloud platform bucket to store all my wordpress images. As many of you know wordpress creates many thumbnails from the original image that was uploaded.

I have been able to link the image from the google bucket to wordpress. But from time to time I update the image. I thought it would have automatically updated the thumbnails as well. But this is not the case.

Scenario - I upload main image into wordpress media library. It creates two other images plus original eg Image.jpg; Image-510x383.jpg; Image-115x85.jpg

Only the Image.jpg is visible in the Google Bucket. Should I reupload the image with a change using gsutil. The main full scale image changes on wordpress live site but the thumbnails remain the old versions.

How do you find were these thumbnailed images are in Google bucket so I can resync them easily as well.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WP-Stateless plugin - it's free. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/

It will manage the process of uploading your images and other files (PDFs, MP3s, etc) to Google Cloud Storage, including all the thumbnails WordPress generates. It supports several modes, including a mode that will delete the local file since it is no longer needed.